# How to modify keras model to get output between 0 to 7 except for just 0 and 1?

Tags: python, keras, classification

I am pretty new to data science and neural network. I have a dataset of unicode sentences which havebeen labeled as 0 and 1 for 'spam' or 'not_spam'. the Model I used for data is the code below(excluding the data preprocessing):

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import LSTM, Activation, Dense, Dropout, Input, Embedding

def RNN():
    inputs = Input(name='inputs',shape=[max_len])

    layer = Embedding(max_words,50,input_length=max_len)(inputs)

    layer = LSTM(64)(layer)

    layer = Dense(256,name='FC1')(layer)

    layer = Activation('relu')(layer)

    layer = Dropout(0.5)(layer)

    layer = Dense(1,name='out_layer')(layer)

    layer = Activation('sigmoid')(layer)
    # sigmoid aka 0 to 1 output

    model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=layer)

    return model


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=RMSprop(),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The predictions are so far so good.

But now I had my data-set modified. I added 6 columns instead of 'spam' column so my data label become an integer between [1-7]. Data-set looks like this (case #1):

```
sentence | category
 sent 1  | 1
 sent 2  | 3
 sent 3  | 2
 sent 4  | 7
   .
   .
   .
```

I know I can add dummy variables and modify it like this one(case#2):

```
sentence | category_1 | category_2 | category_3 |  ...  | category_7 
 sent 1  |     1      |     0      |     0      |       |     0 
 sent 2  |     0      |     0      |     1      |       |     0 
 sent 3  |     0      |     1      |     0      |       |     0 
 sent 4  |     0      |     0      |     0      |       |     1
   .
   .
   .
```

So I'm familiar with feature engineering part for data-set. What actually I'm looking for is to modify the code to have output from model like 1,2,3,4,.. (which implies prediction for each category).

Does anybody know how can I modify the code (The keras model) with as little editing as possible?

Any other recommendation for enhancing accuracy (based on experiences in NLP and Neural Network fields) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing this line `layer = Dense(8,name='out_layer')(layer)` with this `layer = Dense(8,name='out_layer')(layer)` does the job.

For getting an array with 8 values we have to use this:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import LSTM, Activation, Dense, Dropout, Input, Embedding

def RNN():
    inputs = Input(name='inputs',shape=[max_len])

    layer = Embedding(max_words,50,input_length=max_len)(inputs)

    layer = LSTM(64)(layer)

    layer = Dense(256,name='FC1')(layer)

    layer = Activation('relu')(layer)

    layer = Dropout(0.5)(layer)

    layer = Dense(8,name='out_layer')(layer) 

    layer = Activation('sigmoid')(layer)
    # sigmoid aka 0 to 1 output

    model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=layer)

    return model


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=RMSprop(),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're getting one-hot encoded outputs, to decode it back to integer

```
decoded = np.argmax(encoded, axis=1)
```

[check the example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH5EA.png)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for reading my question, thinking it through and replying. your answer seems to be helpful in feature-engineering part if I am right. I actually want to get integer predictions from model ranging from 1 to 7 (which used to be 0 and 1 for the current model which is doing a classification task).

Comment: I would be glad if you put your sample code in the question code, Then your answer would be much more clear.

Comment: After decoding, you will get integers from 0 to 6, just add 1 to all of them. It will give you labels ranging from 1 to 7. I don't know if that's what you're asking.